I was deprived of liquidity by two tokens on the Solana chain ray platform, causing a loss of 10 million
I was deprived of liquidity by two tokens on the Solana chain ray platform, causing a loss of 10 million. It deserves to go to hell and die an infinite number of times. Give me back the money.
this two token
3t8Mzc46tk9w8zUCam8WjGi2JKwxy7LqjBsFF4SgVEU8
https://solscan.io/token/3t8Mzc46tk9w8zUCam8WjGi2JKwxy7LqjBsFF4SgVEU8
6fybpEXE13m7fxEfVhhDNDvV6K1evkLUCkNcSrutgTpL
https://solscan.io/token/6fybpEXE13m7fxEfVhhDNDvV6K1evkLUCkNcSrutgTpL
